# Jasmine is not define error after using jest-circus

Tags: puppeteer, jest-circus

Would like to use `jest.retryTimes()` & for that I have installed jest-circus however while running test getting jasmine not define error .

To achieve above I have added `testRunner: "jest-circus/runner"` in jest.config.js

I am using puppeteer framework with jest test runner.

Exact error :
Test suite failed to run

ReferenceError: jasmine is not defined

at registerAllureReporter (node_modules/jest-allure/dist/setup.js:46:5) at Object. (node_modules/jest-allure/dist/setup.js:49:1)

Comment: Can you paste the exact, full error message from the terminal please? Is it `ReferenceError: jasmine is not defined`?

Comment: Test suite failed to run

ReferenceError: jasmine is not defined

at registerAllureReporter (node_modules/jest-allure/dist/setup.js:46:5)                                            
at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-allure/dist/setup.js:49:1)

Comment: Is [jest-allure](https://github.com/zaqqaz/jest-allure)  a direct dependency of your project? Actually it would help if you'd list all dependencies/devDependencies from your `package.json` and your relevant `jest.config.js` entries as well. It seems jest-allure is not set up properly, but its settings could depend on your actual jest version.

Comment: jsconfig.json as follow 
{ 
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "e92017",
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports.": false,
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths":{-------XYZ------ }
},
"exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

Comment: Package.json "dependencies": {
"babel/core": "7.7.5",
"@babel/Plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "7.7.4",
"@babel/preset-env": "7.7.6",
"allure-commandline": "2.13.0",
"babel-jest": "24.9.0",
"docx": "5.0.2",
"dotenv": "8.2.0",
"eslint": "6.7.2",
"eslint-config-prettier": "6.7.0",
"form-data": "3.0.0",
"Is": "0.0.1-security",
"husky": "3.1.0",
"jest": "24.9.0",
"jest-allure": "0.1.1",
"jest-circus": "*26.0.1",
"jest-junit": "10.0.0",
"lint-staged": "9.0.0",
"node-rest-client": "3.1.0",
"prettier": "1.19.1",
"puppeteer": "2.1.1",
}

Comment: OK, it still seems that **jest-allure** is the culprit. Sorry above I meant the `jest.config.js` file, not `jsconfig.json`. I am curious because I see you have jest 24.9, which requires the following line in `jest.config.js` : `reporters: ["default", "jest-allure"],`. That may be missing. But there can be other conflicting settings in the jest config, or conflict between other npm dependencies.

Comment: jest.config.js as follow
module.exports = { 
setupFilesAfterEnv: ['Jest-allure/dist/setup'], globalSetup: './setup.js',
 globalTeardown: './teardown.js', testEnvironment: './puppeteer-environment.js',
reporters:[
default',
'jest-allure', ['jest-junit', { suiteName: xyz tests ', outputName: 'results.xm' }],
],
testRunner: 'jest-circus/runner',
};

Comment: OK. Sorry in my latest comment I made a wrong suggestion about the "reporters" entry (and I don't know if you've made a change in your config because of this). So: `setupFilesAfterEnv: ['Jest-allure/dist/setup'], ` should be replaced by: `setupFilesAfterEnv: ["jest-allure/dist/setup"]` as you see there are syntactic errors in it.  I don't know if it is a copy-paste error: but in `reporters` and `runners` entry there are some further syntactic mistakes. **But `reporters:[ 'default', 'jest-allure'` should be removed for sure as it is needed only for older jest versions.**

Comment: now i have something { setupFilesAfterEnv: ["jest-allure/dist/setup"], "reporters": [ ["jest-junit", {suitName: 'abc', outputName: 'result.xml'}],["<rootDir>/my-custom-reporter.js"],],testRunner: "jest-circus/runner",
}

Comment: however i am getting npm error i.e failed at the puppeteer@0.11.0 test script.  error: This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above

Comment: In above comment it's reporters not "reporters"

Answer (score 1):

Please check my answer to the similar question regarding undefined jasmine with jest-circus runner being used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66073466/1445507