# Accessing jasmine with testRunner set to jest-circus results in: ReferenceError: jasmine is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, jasmine, jest-circus

On default `jest` allows you to simply access `jasmine` globally. But as soon as you switch the `testRunner` to `jest-circus`, `jasmine` is undefined. Following is a minimal, reproducible example:

**babel.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "current" } }]],
};
```

**jasmine.spec.js**

```js
it("check jasmine", () => {
  console.log(jasmine);
});
```

**jest.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  rootDir: ".",
  testRunner: "jest-circus/runner",
};
```

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "test-jest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-circus": "^26.6.3"
  }
}
```

Running this test will cause following output:

```sh
$ npm test

> test-jest@1.0.0 test /Users/yusufaran/Projects/test/test-jest
> jest

 FAIL  ./jasmine.spec.js
  ✕ check jasmine (1 ms)

  ● check jasmine

    ReferenceError: jasmine is not defined

      1 | it("check jasmine", () => {
    > 2 |   console.log(jasmine);
        |               ^
      3 | });
      4 | 

      at Object.<anonymous> (jasmine.spec.js:2:15)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.01 s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

If you remove/comment the `testRunner` line in `jest.config.js` (so it fallbacks to the default runner) it works as expected.

**Question**

How can I access global `jasmine` object with `testRunner` set to `jest-circus/runner`? If I can't, why?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can’t access jasmine when you use jest-circus. This is by design. jest-circus is a new test runner that was built from scratch. It mimics jasmine functionality for defining tests (i.e., `describe`, `it`, everything except `expect` assertions and spies).

If you depend on jasmine, then `npm install -D jest-jasmine2` and use it in your jest config:

```
{
  testRunner: 'jest-jasmine2'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just adding `testRunner: 'jasmine2'` to jest.config.js did the trick for me

Comment: that's literally what was suggested in the accepted answer..

Comment: Nopes, my answer does not ask you to install jest-jasmine2 nor use jest-jasmine2 for testRunner

Comment: I see i missed the `jest-` here, sorry

Comment: Note that this will not work with Jest 28 (upcoming version at the time of writing), and installing jest-jasmine2 is going to be required by then

Comment: This one solved the problem for me, the other one wth `jest-jasmine2` caused an error.

Comment: @GarouDan was the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'enableGlobally')"?